# Unusual high CPU usage in UITableView

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, core-data

I'm creating an exercise app, and i created a UITableview to show all of the exercises available (roughly 120). And i'm getting the data from CoreData using an NSFetchedResultsController. The problem i'm having is i get really high cpu usage when i'm scrolling through the table. It ranges from 50%-100% depending how fast i scroll.

Here's my cell for row:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? ExerciseCell else {fatalError("Couldn't load appropriate index path for custom cell")}

     let exercise = self.fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)
     cell.exerciseTitle.text = exercise.name

     if let getImage = exercise.image2 {
            let image = UIImage(data: getImage as Data)

                cell.exerciseImage.image = image

        } else {
            cell.exerciseImage.image = nil
        }

    return cell
}
```

I'm not sure if it could be something to do with how i'm converting the image? Or how i have my CoreData setup? Any help would be awesome. Thanks.

Comment: I suspect the repeated calls to `UIImage(data: ` are very expensive.  If this were my code, I'd probably try to fetch the images for all exercises saved in CoreData and cache them somewhere for quick reuse/reloading.  Perhaps before displaying the tableview?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like might be you are doing expensive work on UIImage.

There are guidelines you should follow in order to achieve scrolling seamlessly.

One thumb rule: Try to make `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` method as quick as possible to return cell instances

- **Threading**: Try to do fetching or any computations in background thread instead of main thread ex. here you are creating UIImage instances
- **Rendering**: Don’t perform data binding in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath`, instead perform steps into `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath`
- **Animations**: Some eye opening core graphics performance issue. Refer this: http://asyncdisplaykit.org/docs/corner-rounding.html
- **Caching**: Create your own caching mechanism which can be effective. i.e.

  - Better approach to access coreData result so afterwards it can be quickly accessible
  - Height calculations for your cells
- For dynamic height cells, Don’t initialised instance of cell with bound data to fetch their height, Instead use class method which returns height based on passed width and data to display (Adapter of cell)